# Not opening file for preview from URL in android

Tags: java, android

**Dont know why its not working.**

```
 String url = "http://oknowlee.openrepository.com/oknowledge/bitstream/11283/367366/1/4e94464b-f3c4-41d8-8edc-10ec0ae4f5bb.pdf";    

     Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ur url is not working please check url.

Comment: I want this to open in default directly from url for preview purpose

Comment: I changed the url but still not working.

Comment: http://oknowledge.openrepository.com/oknowledge/bitstream/11283/367366/1/4e94464b-f3c4-41d8-8edc-10ec0ae4f5bb.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You did not add that URL to the intent to open

replace

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
```